# C++ - Performance when declaring enum outside or in class?

Tags: c++

I have a pretty concrete question; Is there any difference in the performance when declaring an enum outside a class and when declaring an enum within the class?
Thanks!

Comment: Enums have no runtime affection whatsoever. They are like integer literals.

Comment: no there will be no performance issue will happen when you declare enum as outside class and inside class

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, where asking a beginner question gets downvoted to hell. Please don't take the downvotes to heart, some people here just aren't very friendly

Comment: Thanks guys, all of you :) @SteveLorimer, gotcha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no performance difference.

Any `enum` or `enum class` declared within *class scope* has it's name bounded to the class' name (in the sense that the name of a class is also a namespace); and [access checking](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access) is performed for its use.

The only real difference here is the access checking, otherwise, the namespace point, is not an issue, because every name in C++ is decared within some namespace (whether global or not).

There is no performance implication.

Comment: *"There is additional performance implication"* - are you saying there *is* a performance implication, or is this a typo?

Comment: @SteveLorimer, It was a typo. fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There is zero performance difference. The enclosing class simply affects the name given to the `enum` and the names which are visible to the `enum`. 
The entire difference is shown below; see how the static asserts reference the two `foo`s, which have different ideas about what `x` means.

```
const int x = 3;
enum foo { z = x };

struct bar {
    static const int x = 4;
    enum foo { z = x };
};

static_assert(z == 3, "from ::x");
static_assert(bar::z == 4, "from bar::x");
```